# Visual Studio 15 xmlns error

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

i have the following code:

```
<Page x:Class="TestApp.Views.MainPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:vm="using:TestApp.ViewModels">

<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:MainPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>
```

and i got this error :

> The name "MainPageViewModel" does not exist in the namespace "using:TestApp.ViewModels"

My viewmodel class looks like this:

```
namespace TestApp.ViewModels
{
    public class MainPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The app build and run fine, but with this error I'm not able to see what I'm doing while I write the xaml.

How can i fix this?

Comment: i have tried to rebuild, and even a clean and build with no luck

Comment: Change your `xmlns:vm="using:TestApp.ViewModels"` to `xmlns:VM="using:TestApp.ViewModels"` and then use as `<VM:MainPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />`. Rebuild the project and try?

Comment: I't the same thing it doesn't work

Comment: This is a far stretch, but last time I encountered this problem it was, because the type wasn't known in the code-behind file. That was using C++/CX, though, and with C# all types in the same namespace should be known. Still, try to add a `using` statement to explicitly introduce your view model type into the code-behind file.

Comment: what version, build and SKU of VS are u running?

Comment: Right now i'm running Visual studio 2017 RC and i still have this issue